# How do I find the total of all the elements in an int array c#

Tags: c#

As it says in the title, is there a code to find out the total of all the numbers in an int array element.

E.G

```
int  [] Football = new int [5];
```

And say all the elements already had values, how would i find the total of them or reference the total of them so i could add it to a variable?

Answer (score 3):

That is quite easy using LINQ:

```
Football.Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the elements. This is basic stuff and should be covered in any [C# tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
int total = 0;
foreach(int i in Football) {
    total += i;
}
```

Or you can use LINQ:

```
int total = Football.Sum();
```

Comment: Worked great thanks very much for the answer and your patience with my newbness!!